# Weird stuff in "Top Questions"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've learned to check first because this happens frequently. This is the first question listed under active.

"modified 16 mins ago Community" -
[Generate random position within object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/generate-random-position-within-object)

The question, however, appears to have been edited the day after posting (2015), answered "Oct 29 '15 at 9:12" and has not been modified since.

"Active: Today" - really? There are only 4 dates visible and they're all from 2015.

What exactly is @Community up to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected, correct behavior.

One of the roles of the Community user (which is not a real person) is to periodically bump old questions that are considered "unanswered" so that they get visibility.

It does this without *actually* editing the question in any material fashion. The bump doesn't even show in the question's timeline. I'm not sure, not being an SE developer, but I'm pretty sure it just writes a new timestamp into the question's "last updated" column in the database, or something similar.

Note that "unanswered" is defined in this context as "having no upvoted or accepted answers."

Comment: I suspected as much and accept. Is there absolutely no reason to indicate that it was bumped? Also, is there an actual expectation that the user simply forgot (for two years) to accept any of the listed answers? After two years (probably more like 2 months), isn't it pretty likely that they've either found an answer elsewhere and/or abandoned their project but forgot to delete the question? If I spend an hour making a diagrammed answer, will Community also evaluate and accept my answer for them? (As un-sarcastically as possible.. :D)

Comment: "Modified by Community" is the indication it was bumped; that message generally won't appear in any other circumstance. A user is not under any obligation to "accept" an answer. Maybe they forgot about the question, or maybe none of the answers actually solved their problems. "Acceptance" shouldn't be the end goal of an answer: correctness and quality should. And other users can vote on the correctness and quality of your answer, it doesn't require the OP. As soon as a question gets an answer and that answer gets an upvote -- from anybody -- it's considered "answered" for this algorithm.

Comment: "having no upvoted or.." - I missed this, on first read, as being an attempt to address the "forgot about my question" people. Gotcha; thanks again.